# Resolvers Seem to Get A Duplicate Injector

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm writing a lazy-loaded module for my Angular 2 application, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to inject a singleton service into both a resolver and component. It seems that the resolver gets an injector which has the same providers as the component, but it is completely isolated from the component injector.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aqGeeiPn5vMh6fFSPnlH?p=preview)

My structure is like this:

- `RootModule`

  - `AppComponent`
  - `LazyLoadedModule`

    - `LazyLoadedComponent`
    - `LazyLoadedComponentResolver`
    - `BackendService`

My `LazyLoadedModule` declares the `LazyLoadedComponent`, and provides both the `LazyLoadedComponentResolver` and `BackendService`. Both the component and resolver attempt to inject the `BackendService`, but each are getting unique instances.

It seems that

- The component gets an `ElementInjector`, which has it's own `BackendService` instance
- The resolver gets an `LazyLoadedModuleInjector`, which has it's own `BackendService` instance

**Is this is correct behavior? Is there no way to inject a singleton into both a resolver and a component?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in the angular router v3.2. One workaround is to downgrade the router to v3.1.1

The fix is still not merged in the latest release. Check this pull request for more information:
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13593

Comment: That seems to be exactly it. Thank you!